# Discord JDA Dependency not found

Tags: maven, discord-jda

I am trying to build a discord application but it can't access the JDA latest version.

Error:
`Dependency 'net.dv8tion:JDA:4.2.1_255' not found`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Discord_BOT</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
            <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1_255</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>dv8tion</id>
            <name>m2-dv8tion</name>
            <url>https://m2.dv8tion.net/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Comment: Could you include the full output from maven? I can get the version just fine: https://m2.dv8tion.net/releases/net/dv8tion/JDA/4.2.1_255/JDA-4.2.1_255.pom

Comment: They fixed it now, i literally didnt change anything and it worked